Manuscript included in special collection by editor?
I have recently submitted my first manuscript to an academic journal. I was notified by an Associate Editor that my manuscript was included in a special collection of the journal, and I need to either accept or reject this suggestion. I need to get an accepted paper before February in order to graduate.

Is this positive for the submission, in terms of the remaining time for acceptance?
Does this mean the reviewers have reached a conclusion?


The editor's message makes no sense if you have the verb tense of things correct here. Are you sure this is a reputable journal?

I don't have further experience with manuscript submissions, but I think it means it will be considered for the special collection if we accept the suggestion. My question is whether this impacts the whole submission timeline in a positive or negative way. Sorry if I was unclear before!

Is your advisor helping you with this, or are you doing it all on your own?

"I need to get an accepted paper before February in order to graduate" I don't know what the average time from submission to acceptance is in your field (in my field it would be pure fantasy to imagine that a paper submitted now will be accepted by February), but I would very strongly recommend that you have a plan B, because February is just around the corner and all sorts of delays can happen in the review process.

Sounds like the associate editor is suggesting your manuscript be included in a particular "special collection" of the journal. These things are collections of papers on a particular topic, e.g. here is a list of special issues (i.e. "special collection") for a MDPI journal.
You are free to agree to, or decline, your paper being included in the collection. There should not be a bias either way in whether your paper is accepted or not. If you agree then your paper shows up on the same webpage as the other papers in the special collection. The most important thing that might change for the peer review process is that special collections have guest editors, and these guest editors would most probably be the ones handling your paper, if you agree with the move.
As for speed of review process: this depends most on how active your editor is. If the associate editor is a guest editor of the special collection, then they're likely to be active since they're already in contact with you, so agreeing with the move might help. (Or not. The associate editor might go inactive, or the reviewers might be late, etc.)
Finally, your paper presumably has not been reviewed yet, and there is no decision yet.

"Included" and "accepted" aren't the same thing. Normally the standards for acceptance into a special issue are a bit higher than in general, assuming reputable journals only of course.
Ask the editor whether that their use of "inclusion" means acceptance. For a reputable journal, being accepted into a special issue is a good thing. Normally really good. The reason is limited space, especially for print journals.
The best case is that the paper is considered so good that short-cuts have been taken to get it into a special issue. And in that "best case" it would probably mean earlier acceptance.
And consider whether this is a reputable journal as Bryan Krause suggests in a comment. For a reputable journal where the editor says it has been accepted, rather than just that "consideration has been moved" then say yes, I'd guess.
Special issues also normally have a fairly fixed publication date, also implying earlier decisions. Normally, a paper can be put off to future issues when there are issues.
But ask. It is the only way to know. Do it now.

"Normally the standards for acceptance into a special issue are a bit higher than in general." - I think this is an outdated view. Nowadays, "special issues" are highly associated with predatory publishing practices, where journals solicit people to be "guest editors" by sending them spam emails full of praise, then expect them to gather a bunch of submissions to make the journal money, without particular care for quality. Some fill them with their own papers. Of course, some reputable journals may still do the old school special issue, but I would be very, very wary.

@BryanKrause, I'm only speaking for reputable journals, of course.

Even back in the day, special issues in my field often had a lower standard for acceptance than normal issues. People would propose a special issue arising from a conference, workshop or a particular funding round. The special issue editors solicited papers from people they'd been working with and already knew. They had less investment than regular editors in maintaining the reputation of the journal and more in getting the work of the group published.
